# Finding $x$ for which $ \prod_{n=0}^{44} (1 + \tan(x+n)^\circ)=2^{23} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

> Find the value of $x$ for which
> $$ \prod_{n=0}^{44} (1 + \tan(x+n)^\circ)=2^{23} $$
> The answer is $1$.

I converted $\tan$ in terms of $\sin$ and $\cos$, and I ended up on
$$ \prod_{n=0}^{44} \frac{\sin(45+n+x)^\circ}{\cos(n+x)^\circ}=\sqrt{2} $$

Please help me solve this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. Are your angles in radians or degrees?

Comment: I assume the rather arbitrary $23$ is in reference to $2023$, which is a common type of inclusion in many yearly contest-math problems. If that's true, then it's important to mention, or include as a tag, as there are policies surrounding answering contest-math problems here.

Answer (score 1):

We note the fact that
$$\sin n + \cos n = \sqrt{2}\cos (45-n)$$
and thus
\begin{align*}
\prod \limits_{n=1}^{45} {\left( 1 +\tan n \right)} &= 2\times \prod\limits_{n=1}^{44} {\frac{\sqrt{2} \cos (45-n)}{\cos n}}\\
&= {{2}^{23}}
\end{align*}
and hence $x=1$ is one solution of the given equation.

But, $x=1$ is of course not the only solution as the $\tan$ function is periodic.

Comment: We must found **all** $x$.

Comment: @EdwardTurJ of course, if $1$ is a solution, then so must be $181$, $361$,... basically everything of the form $180k+1$. 
The tricky part is to show that $x=1$ is the only solution if restricted to $0\le x\le 180$. For that, we need to somehow argue that the given function is one-one in that domain- shouldn't be a difficult exercise, but I can't immediately see a way.